# Can 'consistently' be used when there are only three data points?

Tags: word-usage

I want to use 'consistently' but I'm worried that it may be inappropriate because there are only three data points/three years. Three years are not a long time. The dictionary says [the adverb 'consistently' describes something that's done the same way for **a long time**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/consistently). Do I need more data pints to use 'consistently'?

> Only around 20 million households consistently having a yearly income
> of $50,000 to $74,999 in all three years. (I wrote it)

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can use the chart itself to justify referring to ***20 million households** consistently having [some income level]*. The income of many households will rise or fall within the 4 years between samplings, placing them in different "income quintiles". You'd need a much more complicated chart to tell us anything about how many households ***consistently*** remained in the same income quintile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a further problem with the proposed sentence. This chart shows how *many* households fall into each income bracket. An individual household could move from bracket to bracket between these years. To say "20 million households consistently have an income of ___" implies that all of these 20 million households are experiencing financial consistency, but that's not necessarily what the data tells us. It *could* be reasonable to say "Consistently, 20 million households have..." because now "consistently" is talking about the whole graph rather than the households. EXCEPT that, you're right, this is statistics and three data points is not enough of a "sample size." I might choose something more direct like "in each of the three years..."

Answer (score 0):

Your instinct is right about not using that word (or probably any qualifier). You are simply state a fact about the data shown not a general fact about the number of people in an income bracket. "Only around20 million households **consistently** have a yearly income of $50,000 to $74,999 **in all three years**." ... the qualifiers, here in bold, seem to clash making the sentance read badly. In practice a reader would have to read back to work out what you meant and then would ignore the word consistently. Also note that I have replaced having with have to make this a complete grammatical sentance. With "having" it is a noun-phrase rather than a sentance, which might be ok as a title, but still not good.